# Python object. How to pass a value to one specific method

Tags: python, object, methods

I have a Python object that represents a camera dolly that moves along a track. The class can store and report its position along the track. I have three methods:

1. `MoveBy` - which gets the distance from another object (`Movie.yIncrement`)
2. `MoveTo` - which I want to pass a value between 0 and the length of the track
3. `Reset` - which should return the
   dolly to the start of the track

I think I've misunderstood how to call the `MoveTo` method with a value?

```
class Dolly:
    name = "Dolly"
    DollyOrigin2CamCL = 30 #subject to actually constructing the dolly
    DollyLengthY = 130 #subject to actually constructing the dolly
    #constructor
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.pos = pos 
        #reset() # <---can I do this here?
    #methods
    def moveBy(self):
        print("moving by " + Movie.yIncrement)
        #check pos + incrementY doesn't exceed Track.length - camera centreline to dolly end distance (need to set this up)
        #Dolly motor  control to move 'increment' distance away from origin
        #ensure that the code that calls this method updates Dolly.pos, by the incrementY
    def moveTo(self,goTo):
        print("moving directly to position " + self.goTo)
        #Make sure dolly doesn't run off the Track.startY or Track.endY (inclding the dolly size)
    def reset(self):
        print("returning to startY (" + Movie.startY + ")")
        #Make sure dolly doesn't run off the Track.startY - include dolly local 0 to camera centreline offset
        #After reset, assert pos is zero
    def stepRegime(self):
        #Take Movie.yIncrement and work out which type of motor control to use to traverse quickly and accurately
        print("resetting")

D1 = Dolly(20)
print(D1.pos)
print(D1.DollyOrigin2CamCL)
print(D1.DollyLengthY)
D1.moveBy
D1.moveTo(100)
```

Comment: Why do you think so? Do you get an error?

Comment: Note that per [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names) it is conventional to name your methods using snakecase (ie., `move_by` rather than `moveBy`). You can continue naming the functions as you have, there's nothing inherently wrong with those names, but in practice you'll end up with inconsistency when you start using libraries as they largely follow this convention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may have forgot to update the attribute when calling the `moveTo()`method.

It should be something like:

```py
    def moveTo(self,goTo):
        self.goTo = goTo
        print(f"moving directly to position {self.goTo} ")
        #Make sure dolly doesn't run off the Track.startY or Track.endY (inclding the dolly size)
```

Also, even if a method does not require extra parameters, you need to call them by using the parentheses, otherwise you're just accessing the function without executing it.
So last part of your code should be:

```py
D1.moveBy()
D1.moveTo(100)
```

Regarding instead the comment in your constructor. You can indeed call methods of the instance from the constructor. When calling a method of the instance inside a class you need to first access the instance, by using the `self` variable and then call the methods you wish to call

```py
    #constructor
    def __init__(self, pos):
        self.pos = pos 
        self.reset() # <---now you can
```

---

Regarding your last comment:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, username: str, plain_password: str):
        self.username = username
        # we can't have the plain password accessible for the user instance, thus we encrypt it
        self.encrypted_password = self.encrypt_password(plain_password)

    def encrypt_password(self, plain_password: str) -> str:
        return "HASHED" + plain_password + "HASHED"


user = User("user", "password")
print(user.username) # returns "user"
print(user.encrypted_password) # returns "HASHEDpasswordHASHED"
print(user.plain_password) # throws AttributeError
```

Comment: Perfect. Working now (apart from having to convert my ints & floats to str to make the print string concatenation work). Thank you

Comment: I suggest you to use fstrings for that. for example: `f"moving directly to position {self.goTo}"`. You can learn more [here](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/), very useful stuff

Comment: Thanks for the f-string lead.

Comment: Just to round out the answer about calling an instance's method within the constructor; if that method also takes a class parameter, for example the value of `pos` , then I presume that also takes a `self` qualifier i.e. `self.reset(self.pos)`?

Comment: Yep you can do it. But it might be a bit redundant because the self object already contains the `pos`attribute. Usually you may want to do it when you want to initialize an object but you do not need to store values passed to initialize it. I edited my answer with a base example at the end. I used type hints but you can ignore them if you're not used to types